# proper usage of css selectors using Cascadia with Julia

Tags: dom, web-scraping, css-selectors, julia

Absolute web scraping beginner with no css selector experience.

Project: I am trying to write a basic Julia script in order to pull a current options price from https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/TSLA/options

My research: After taking a first look at how to pull data automatically from the web into julia, i was led to look to css selectors and the packages HTTP and Cascadia. This is a topic that I have never dealt with but tried to follow examples (which will be appended to the end of this question) in order figure it out. Ultimately I havnt.

Problem: I thought that i could use developer tool in chrome or the source code to isolate the specific tag or part to then reference in the page referenced given above. Nothing I have used works, my search returns empty results.

Below is both one of my many attempts as well as a screenshot and current code. Any insight much appreciated!

[example of target data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSUf7.jpg)
[another example of target data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Ymc.jpg)

```
using HTTP, Gumbo, Cascadia
page = HTTP.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/TSLA/options
body = String(page.body);
html = parsehtml(body);
qres = eachmatch(sel".option_cell strike current fixed--cell", html.root);
```

https://www.juliabloggers.com/julia-introduction-to-web-scraping-phivolcs-seismic-events/

https://julia.school/julia/scraping/

Comment: Just be aware you are probably violating their [T&C](https://www.marketwatch.com/site/subscriber-agreement) specifically 8.4.1

Comment: When possible, please paste relevant text in your question instead of linking to an image.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues. First, there are two underscores in `.option_cell`. Second, your query string doesn't do what you think it does. The syntax `a b c` means `b` is a descendent of `a` and `b` is a descendant of `c`. To describe a selector that matches a single node with several attributes simultaneously, you concatenate the attributes without spaces in between. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

```
julia> qres = eachmatch(sel".option__cell.strike.current.fixed--cell", html.root)
3-element Vector{HTMLNode}:
 HTMLElement{:div}:<div class="option__cell strike current fixed--cell">
  589.89
</div>


 HTMLElement{:div}:<div class="option__cell strike current fixed--cell">
  589.89
</div>


 HTMLElement{:div}:<div class="option__cell strike current fixed--cell">
  589.89
</div>
```